# Cannot resolve settings_container

Tags: android, kotlin

The Android official [page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings) says to create the preferences Activity this way:

```
class MySettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.settings_container, MySettingsFragment())
                .commit()
    }
}
```

When I do that, *R.id.settings_container* cannot be resolved. Should I simply use the automatic option "Create id value resource 'settings_container'", or that resource should be created somehow else to be meaningful?

Comment: I just solved the problem by adding of this line to the Activity's Layout:
android:id="@+id/settings_container"

Comment: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`use android.R.id.content` (which is used in `onCreate()` also)